# Passar informação entre duas páginas PHP

Tags: php, laravel, controller, view, laravel-blade

boa tarde! Eu estou tendo o seguinte problema: eu tenho uma página php denominada *localidade* que possui os campos "nome" e "cidade". No campo nome, eu digito o nome da localidade, como por exemplo, "Rincão Bonito", e no campo cidade eu recupero de uma tabela *tebelaCidades*. Acontece que quando eu clico no botão "Pesquisar", por meio da url do controller, a página que contém a tabela de cidades é acessada, ou seja, se antes o link era http://jfsjunior.tcc.sistema/localidade/cadastro, agora se torna http://jfsjunior.tcc.sistema/cidade/pesquisaCidade/tela-localidade. Quando eu clico em selecionar, o dado é carregado no input da cidade corretamente, mas o que o nome que eu digitei no campo nome volta vazio. Eu sei que como eu chamo a página localidade para inserir os dados da cidade, então a página é renderizada e, logo, todo campo que tinha sido preenchido, volta vazio. Então a questão é: como eu posso resolver esse problema?

Obs.: estou usando o framework Laravel (template engine Blade).

Desde de já agradeço.

Comment: Eu acho que o problema está na construção da aplicação. Você manda para outra página para pesquisar a localidade e, em seguida, retorna para  a mesma página com os dados preenchidos? Não seria melhor usar AJAX?

Comment: Pois é @Wallace Maxters, já me disseram isso, mas eu não tenho muito conhecimento sobre ajax, e infelizmente não tenho tempo (tcc), para estudar Ajax, daí publiquei com a esperança que alguém tivesse passado por algo semelhante e pudesse compartilhar suas conquistas ou como conseguiu resolver o problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No botão coloque coloque um evento onClick assim:

```
 <a onclick="procuraPelaCidade()">
```

Crie um *javascript* simples

```
function procuraPelaCidade(){
   var nome = document.getElementById("#idDoCampoNome").value;
   var cidade = document.getElementById("#idDoCampoCidade").value;
   window.location = "jfsjunior.tcc.sistema/localidade/"+cidade+"/"+nome;
}
```

Se voce está usando laravel, você pode passar os dados que precisar pela rota.
Por exemplo,

```
Route::get('jfsjunior.tcc.sistema/localidade/{cidade}/{nome}',['as'=>'localidade.view', 'uses'=>'nomeDoController@view']);
```

Não precisa ser exatamente assim, pode passar o nome da cidade e nome, como você deseja, é so um exemplo.

Dentro do nomeDoController faça um **function** assim:

```
 public function view($cidade, $nome){
   return view('tela-localidade', compact('cidade','nome'))
 }
```

Crie uma página nova tela-localidade.blade.php ou altere aquela mesma página para com inputs assim:

```
  @if($cidade != null)
  <input id="idDoCampoCidade" value="{{$cidade}}">
  @endif
  @if($nome != null)
  <input id="idDoCampoNome" value="{{$nome}}">
  @endif
```

Seria realmente mais facil usando um ajax, mas creio que assim funcione também. Se tiver alguma falha de codigo minha, parta da ideia de redirecionamento de paginas por javascript, simples. Crie uma rota com os parametros desejados. Manipule o redirecionamento com valores passados dentro do controller da rota. Trate esses mesmos valores pelo blade.

Comment: então, eu capturaria os dados da página localidade, faria a pesquisa na página pesquisaCidade e depois carregaria a página localidade com os dados capturados previamente junto com a cidade selecionada? Mas no caso, se são mais de dois dados? Assim, e tenho outras telas com o mesmo problema e têm mais campos (indiquei a da localidade por ser mais simples). Ficaria complexa a url não?

Comment: Você pode passar multiplos valores pela url sim, ou esse valor passado pode ser um json ou array. Se nao me engano. Voce so precisa fazer com que as rotas na pasta routes, no arquivo web.php aceitem valores na url. E depois manipule pelo metodo responsavel pela contrução da pagina. Entendeu?

Comment: Entendi... então eu posso passar um array pela url? Daí creio que fique melhor... vou pesquisar a respeito e implementar e posto o resultado!

Comment: De uma olhada aqui:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/not-able-to-pass-this-array-to-controller-through-route

E aqui tambem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359419/laravel-redirectroute-with-an-array-parameter

Comment: Espero ter ajudado em algo

Comment: Obrigado João V. Araújo!